# How can I use canvas outside the onDraw method?

Tags: java, android, parameters, android-canvas, ondraw

I need to draw something on the same canvas that onDraw() get access to.

This works fine as long as I am inside OnDraw(), but I don't know how to get that canvas when I'm outside.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.doSomething  // works fine
}

//new method to draw omething on the same canvas
mydraw(how to get canvas in here?){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to send canvas to your own method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    yourMethod(canvas);
}

void yourMethod(Canvas canvas){
    //TODO
    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

onDraw is called by the system, you should call do your drawing in there
you could always pass he Canvas as a parameter to your myDraw method

Comment: Ok, how do I pass the Canvas to myDraw() ?

Comment: void myDraw(Canvas canvas){ ... } then myDraw(canvas) from inside your override of onDraw